# Is there a specific type of double sided tape and glue to use when installing vinyl?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I am working with those soft backed cushion vinyl.

When installing vinyl I know you need to put double sided tape at the sides.  Tape comes in many forms so is there a specific type of double sided tape to use when installing vinyl or will any generic double sided tape do?

Also I want to ask the same about glue which you normally put at the center, is there a specific type of glue and is this step optional?

Comment: Have you sorted the other floor problems? Oh and a glue that does not off-gas?

Comment: There should be some pretty specific instructions that were included with the vinyl. Backing can be different.

Comment: I have never heard of using double-sided tape for any kind of vinyl flooring product. The manufacture of the vinyl should have specific instructions for how to install.

Comment: I have to agree with Alaska man+ . I have installed and paid for many floors and have never seen or used double stick tape. I have done perimeter only glue on some brands as suggested by the MFG but no double stick unless this is a new thing i haven’t seen yet.

Comment: @AlaskaMan https://home.tarkett.com/en_EU/node/how-to-install-your-vinyl-flooring-801 it is referred to as loose lay by tarkett.

Comment: @EdBeal As above but since its considered half loose perhaps its not a proper perfect installation.